how to use Lambda Function to send automated emails
im trying to use Lambda to create a function that will allow me to send an automated email that says good morning everyday at a specific time. this is for a class project.
the code i currently have for the function is:
obviously where i wrote email i will be inputing the corresponding email
// index.mjs

import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const ses = new AWS.SES({ region: 'us-east-1' });

export async function handler(event, context) {
    const params = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: ['djdand4@gmail.com'],
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: { Data: 'Good morning!' },
            },
            Subject: { Data: 'Good Morning Greeting' },
        },
        Source: 'danielcohen.4c@gmail.com',
    };

    try {
        await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
        console.log('Email sent successfully');
        return { statusCode: 200, body: 'Email sent successfully' };
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error sending email:', err);
        return { statusCode: 500, body: 'Error sending email' };
    }
}



The Lambda documentation has plenty of good examples. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html for one

Doe the code work? Is there a particular problem or error message? Amazon SES will be in 'sandbox mode' so you will need to verify any email addresses it uses. Alternatively, you could point your code at your own email server (eg gmail) instead of uses Amazon SES.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please read the following docs -

Sending an e-mail using SES+Lambda. Doc - https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses
Using eventbridge to execute this lambda at specific time each day. Doc - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html

